cannot find node installation after running colcon build
This is a problem that I am having across both of my Jazzy and Humble workspaces.
After running to colcon build, and navigating to my lib folder, I cannot find the installation for py_node.
I've setup my setup.py and my setup.cfg files as:
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

package_name = 'my_py_pkg'

setup(
    name=package_name,
    version='0.0.0',
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['test']),
    data_files=[
        ('share/ament_index/resource_index/packages',
            ['resource/' + package_name]),
        ('share/' + package_name, ['package.xml']),
    ],
    install_requires=['setuptools'],
    zip_safe=True,
    maintainer='sgq',
    maintainer_email='144968837+sangregoriokimpo@users.noreply.github.com',
    description='TODO: Package description',
    license='TODO: License declaration',
    tests_require=['pytest'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            "py_node = my_py_pkg.my_first_node:main"
        ],
    },
)

[develop]
script_dir=$base/lib/my_py_pkg
[install]
install_scripts=$base/lib/my_py_pkg

After running colcon build --packages-select my_py_pkg  I've navigated to:
sgq@sgq-Laptop-16-AMD-Ryzen-7040-Series:~/ros2_ws$ cd install/
sgq@sgq-Laptop-16-AMD-Ryzen-7040-Series:~/ros2_ws/install$ cd my_py_pkg/
sgq@sgq-Laptop-16-AMD-Ryzen-7040-Series:~/ros2_ws/install/my_py_pkg$ ls
lib  share
sgq@sgq-Laptop-16-AMD-Ryzen-7040-Series:~/ros2_ws/install/my_py_pkg$ cd lib
sgq@sgq-Laptop-16-AMD-Ryzen-7040-Series:~/ros2_ws/install/my_py_pkg/lib$ ls
python3.12
sgq@sgq-Laptop-16-AMD-Ryzen-7040-Series:~/ros2_ws/install/my_py_pkg/lib$ cd python3.12/
sgq@sgq-Laptop-16-AMD-Ryzen-7040-Series:~/ros2_ws/install/my_py_pkg/lib/python3.12$ ls
site-packages
sgq@sgq-Laptop-16-AMD-Ryzen-7040-Series:~/ros2_ws/install/my_py_pkg/lib/python3.12$ cd site-packages/
sgq@sgq-Laptop-16-AMD-Ryzen-7040-Series:~/ros2_ws/install/my_py_pkg/lib/python3.12/site-packages$ ls
my_py_pkg  my_py_pkg-0.0.0-py3.12.egg-info
sgq@sgq-Laptop-16-AMD-Ryzen-7040-Series:~/ros2_ws/install/my_py_pkg/lib/python3.12/site-packages$ cd my_py_pkg
sgq@sgq-Laptop-16-AMD-Ryzen-7040-Series:~/ros2_ws/install/my_py_pkg/lib/python3.12/site-packages/my_py_pkg$ ls
__init__.py  my_first_node.py  __pycache__
sgq@sgq-Laptop-16-AMD-Ryzen-7040-Series:~/ros2_ws/install/my_py_pkg/lib/python3.12/site-packages/my_py_pkg$ 

As you can see, I cannot find the installation that colcon build was supposed to make. I am following a udemy course from backend robotics, and his file structure is different than mine.
I've performed the same commands in my Humble workspace:
sgq@sgq-vm:~/ros2_ws$ colcon build --packages-select my_py_pkg
Starting >>> my_py_pkg
Finished <<< my_py_pkg [0.49s]          

Summary: 1 package finished [0.62s]
sgq@sgq-vm:~/ros2_ws$ cd install
sgq@sgq-vm:~/ros2_ws/install$ ls
COLCON_IGNORE     _local_setup_util_ps1.py  my_py_pkg   setup.zsh
local_setup.bash  _local_setup_util_sh.py   setup.bash
local_setup.ps1   local_setup.zsh           setup.ps1
local_setup.sh    my_cpp_pkg                setup.sh
sgq@sgq-vm:~/ros2_ws/install$ cd my_py_pkg/
sgq@sgq-vm:~/ros2_ws/install/my_py_pkg$ ls
lib  share
sgq@sgq-vm:~/ros2_ws/install/my_py_pkg$ cd lib
sgq@sgq-vm:~/ros2_ws/install/my_py_pkg/lib$ ls
python3.10
sgq@sgq-vm:~/ros2_ws/install/my_py_pkg/lib$ cd python3.10/
sgq@sgq-vm:~/ros2_ws/install/my_py_pkg/lib/python3.10$ ls
site-packages
sgq@sgq-vm:~/ros2_ws/install/my_py_pkg/lib/python3.10$ cd site-packages/
sgq@sgq-vm:~/ros2_ws/install/my_py_pkg/lib/python3.10/site-packages$ ls
my_py_pkg  my_py_pkg-0.0.0-py3.10.egg-info
sgq@sgq-vm:~/ros2_ws/install/my_py_pkg/lib/python3.10/site-packages$ 

Across both workspaces, I cannot find py_node as outlined by the setup.py and setup.cfg files after running colcon build.

I think I've found the issue,
the path in setup.py and setup.cfg is defined as: $base/lib/my_py_pkg , however when navigating to the lib folder, my_py_pkg isn't a directory, so colcon fails to generate an installation in that folder since it doesnt exist?
I thought that colcon build would autogenerate that directory?
Is this the correct issue? I don't know if I should make the directory, im scared itll fuck up the ROS2 environment.

the fix was changing:
"py_node = my_py_pkg.my_first_node:main"
to:
'py_node = my_py_pkg.my_first_node:main'

Can you post this as a self answer so others who encounter this save issue can know it's solved and find your answer more quickly?
